# XML/HTML - Update XML file with 1 hour interval

Tags: html, xml, request, xmlhttprequest

I'm totally green to XML, but I've heard that with decent knowledge you can set some kind of listener on your www to download some external XML files with a specified interval.

Could anybody there tell me something more on this case, how do we achieve that?

Specifically - my **website** should check every hour if `offer.xml` file on other server (being external API i use on website) is different than the one we have on **website** already. If it is, then it should download it and replace the old one with updated offers.

Answer (score 0):

For HTML the code (inside the head) to refresh a page is:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3600">
```

Content is in seconds

> [Note](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_http_equiv.asp): The value "refresh" should be used carefully, as it takes the control of a page away from the user. Using "refresh" will cause a failure in W3C's Web Content Accessibility Guidelines.